# Redirect https to http on ispconfig+apache

Tags: apache, http, redirect, https

I know that question has already been asked, but for some reason, no matter how I try, redirect from https to http just doesn't work. I tried my default approach to redirect (always worked perfectly fine with http to https, thought it would go that smooth the other way as well) and a few solutions from here, but no effect. For now, this is the last method I've tried:

In Apache sites-available directory, I modified relevant .vhost entry, so the changed part now looks like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/SOMEWEBSITE/web>
                            Options FollowSymLinks
                            AllowOverride All
                            Order allow,deny
                            Allow from all
                            RewriteEngine On
                             RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
                             RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
            </Directory>
            <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web>
                            Options FollowSymLinks
                            AllowOverride All
                            Order allow,deny
                            Allow from all
                            RewriteEngine On
                             RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
                             RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
            </Directory>
```

Still, connecting via `https://SOMEWEBSITE` gives me standard apache blank site 
(It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.)

I tried inserting the rewrite rules directly in VirtualHost block and modyfing site's .htaccess file (same effect as above), also tried to create VirtualHost listening on port 443 and redirecting traffic to http, but this approach gave me an SSL error. Is there any other way or something I might be doing wrong? Or is that some ISPConfig issue I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369266/redirecting-https-to-http-ispconfig-apache) solution, here on stackoverflow. It is not done within ISPConfig, but I do not think there is a way to do this from within the ISPConfig GUI anyway.